# 排他処理終了後の戻り値

Tags: ios, swift

複数のスレッドから扱うメモリーデータをアクセスする場合に排他をかけたいと考えています。
メモリーデータへのset/get/updateの関数があり、updateの関数では更新した結果を戻したいと考えています。
その場合、どのようにするのが一般的なのでしょうか。

現状は以下のようにすればどうだろうと考えています。

```
func set(input: Int) {
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    var retval:Int!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

        self.クラスデータ = input

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
}


func get() -> Int{
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    var retval:Int!
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

        retval = self.クラスデータ

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    return retval
}
```

（ご指摘により、質問を修正しました）

Comment: 排他処理と言うのはあまり一般的な言い方ではなく、排他制御と言うことの方が多いと思いますが、排他制御と言うのは複数の事柄が同時には起こらないようにする制御のことで、極めて広い範囲を表す用語です。従って場面や目的によって様々な手法があり、場合によっては複数の手法が提供されていることも少なくありませんし、その中には普通に値を返せる場合も多く含まれます。キューによる処理の直列化が念頭にあるようですが、もしかしたら非同期処理一般を「排他処理」と呼んでいるだけのようにも読めます。どのような場面でどんな処理をして、何を戻り値として返すことを想定しているのか、もう少し具体的に書かれた方が適切な回答を得られると思いますよ。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。大変勉強になります。
現状の用途としては複数のスレッド（タスク）から扱うメモリーデータをアクセスするときに排他をかけたい…と考えている次第です。
メモリーデータへのset/get/updateの関数があり、updateの関数では更新した結果を戻したいと考えています。

そこで、set/get/updateを処理するキューを用意して、直列に処理をすれば、排他がかけられると考えているのですが、
戻り値を取得する場合、どのようにすれば一番いいのかがよくわからずに困っています。
セマフォなどもあるみたいなのですが、
オペレーションキューまたはディスパッチキューのほうが推奨されている…ときいたことがあり、キューを使用する場合、
呼び元に戻り値をどのようにすると返せるのでしょうか。
それとも、一般的な方法がほかにもあるのでしょうか。

Comment: ご丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。「現状の用途としては複数のスレッド（タスク）から扱うメモリーデータをアクセスするときに排他をかけたい」「セマフォなどもあるみたいなのですが、 オペレーションキューまたはディスパッチキューのほうが推奨されている」まったくの誤解です。ご説明頂いたような「複数のスレッドから同時にアクセスされると不整合を起こしてしまうようなメモリーデータ」のアクセスに排他制御を導入するのであれば、セマフォもしくはNSObjectのロック機構(@synchronizedといったキーワードが使われています)を使用するのが常道で、「非同期の通信処理を呼び出した後同期化(終了待ち)をするな」と口を酸っぱくしているAppleでさえ、多数のsample codeにセマフォや@synchronizedを使用しています。「オペレーションキューまたはディスパッチキューを使用する」という前提を外して頂ければ、いくらでも実例は御呈示できますので、キューの使い方に限ったご回答をお求めなのか、あなたのおっしゃるような排他制御について質問される(質問自体を修正される)のかは、ご判断ください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。連絡が遅くなり本当に申し訳ありません。
大変参考になりました。
今回対処したい部分に関してはセマフォか「@synchronized」を使用したいと考えます。ありがとうございます。
ちなみに、勉強のためにも実例などいただけると助かります。


また今回の質問とは異なりますが、
「オペレーションキューまたはディスパッチキューを使用する」などの処理結果を返したい場合は
一般的にはどのような手法を利用しているのでしょうか？
Notificationなどでobserverに通知するようなやり方なのでしょうか。
＃質問にあっていない、別スレッドを立てるべきなどありましたら教えてください。

Comment: どちらのご質問もコメントとして書き込むには少々つらいものがあります。ご自分の質問は編集可能かと思いますので、質問内容を絞り込んだ形に編集してみていただけますでしょうか。こちらのサイトの趣旨から2種類の質問が混在するのは好まれませんので、もうひとつ別の質問スレを立てた方が良いかもしれません。その際には不完全な仮想的コードでも構いませんので、ご自身が念頭に置かれている処理を具体的に書きあらわすと、よりたくさんの方々からの回答が期待できると思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

最初に前提条件として、その`クラスデータ`の操作は(排他制御は必要であるが)1回あたりの処理時間はせいぜいマイクロ秒のオーダーで終了するようなデータ構造(DictionaryやArray, Setなどはみな該当します)であるものとしておきます。

編集後にご掲載のコードは、「非同期処理の待ち合わせ」としては典型的なパターンですが、前提条件に合致するようなデータ構造を操作する場合の排他制御としては、あまり適切とは言えません。

このような排他制御の場合にsemaphoreを用いる際の基本は、

- 排他されるべき一つの資源ごとに一つのsemaphoreを用意する
- 使う前にwait
- 使い終わったらsignal

と言うことです。

具体的には次のような感じになります。

```
var クラスデータ_semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1)
var クラスデータ = (クラスデータの初期化)
```

のように、排他制御したいデータ構造と対になるようにして、初期値が1になるようなsemaphoreを作成します。この`1`は、排他制御される資源を同時に使用できるスレッドが一つだけであることを表しています。それを実際に使う場合は、以下のようになります。

```
    func set(input: Int) {
        //使う前にsemaphoreのカウンター(使える資源数)が1以上になるのを待つ
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(クラスデータ_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

        self.クラスデータ = input

        //使い終わったらsemaphoreのカウンターを1増やして資源の使用終了を通知する
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(クラスデータ_semaphore)
    }


    func get() -> Int {
        let retval: Int
        //使う前にsemaphoreのカウンター(使える資源数)が1以上になるのを待つ
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(クラスデータ_semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

        retval = self.クラスデータ

        //使い終わったらsemaphoreのカウンターを1増やして資源の使用終了を通知する
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(クラスデータ_semaphore)

        return retval
    }
```

いかがでしょうか。わかりにくいところがあればお知らせください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
本当にわかりやすく、勉強になりました。さっそく参考にさせていただきます。